# How do I create scalable horizontal and vertical images?

Tags: html, css, image, image-scaling, image-size

I am working with several images that are set up as inline-block and overflow:scroll.

Currently all images are within the same class = "parent-container" but only the horizontal images are scaling, my vertical images are staying the same size when the screen changes size.

I am looking for *all* my images to scale.

My HTML

```
<div class="parent-container">

<div class="container">
<img src="1.jpg" alt="" class="image" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="container">
<img src="2.jpg" alt="" class="image" style="width:100%">
</div>

 <div class="container">
<img src="3.jpg" alt="" class="image" style="width:100%">
</div>


 <div class="container">
<img src="4.jpg" alt="" class="image" style="width:100%">
</div>

 <div class="container">
<img src="5.jpg" alt="" class="image" style="width:100%">
</div>

</div>
```

My CSS

```
.parent-container {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1175px;
 height: auto;
 padding: auto;
 overflow: scroll;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 margin-left: 35px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 white-space: nowrap;
 display: inline-block;
}

.container {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
}

.image {
opacity: 1;
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
transition: .5s ease;
backface-visibility: hidden;
padding-right: 15px;
}


.parent-container .container .image {
width: auto\9; /* IE8 */
}
```

Thank you!

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/kjfomeze/

Comment: Please show the demo of the current code

Comment: I updated my post with a working example, let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `object-fit: cover;` to your images, with a fixed `height`. This should scale your images.

```css
.parent-container {
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 1175px;
   height: auto;
   padding: auto;
   overflow: scroll;
   overflow-y: hidden;
   margin-left: 35px;
   margin-top: 5px;
   white-space: nowrap;
   display: inline-block;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.image {
  opacity: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">

  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" alt="" class="image" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x150/000/fff" alt="" class="image" style="width:100%">
  </div>

   <div class="container">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff" alt="" class="image" style="width:100%">
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: I tried this and instead of the images scaling (getting smaller with a smaller screen) they just stayed the same size no matter the screen size. Am I missing something?